# How to MySQL Workbench to generate a database relationship diagram?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

In MySQL Workbench, I connected to one database. How can I generate a database relationship diagram?  I know in MSSQL server, they have that functionality.

Answer (score 0):

If this is for a new EERD and not from an existing DB, click on File right under the first tab in workbench on the left side.  Select `New model` from the drop down list. A new window will pop up. In the top-middle you should see a picture that looks like a graph and says `Add Diagram`, click on that. This will open up a new tab that says `EER Diagram`.

If it is from an existing database, open your connection in mysql.  Click on the `Database` option on the top-left of center.  You should see something that says `Reverse Engineer`. This will bring up a a wizard that will prompt you for a connection to which database you want to make into an EERD. Follow the steps (by clicking next). This will eventually open up a the EERD window on a new tab with the schema you have chosen inside of it.